# open a jpeg image from binary format

Tags: binary, format, type-conversion, jpeg

I have a binary file that I want to open as (or to convert to) jpeg image.
The file is only supposed by me to be a jpeg within a binary format, therefore I include a part of it so that You can tell me if I'm wrong ('cause unfortunately I never saw one of those before):

```
0000000000 0E 03 13 01 00 10 00 00 EC B0 00 1E 00 01 00 00 [................]
0000000016 00 CA 00 00 00 5C 00 0F 00 01 00 00 01 26 00 00 [.....\.......&..]
0000000032 00 00 01 2F 00 01 00 00 01 26 00 00 83 B2 00 6A [.../.....&.....j]
0000000048 00 01 00 00 84 D8 00 00 00 04 01 2C 00 01 00 00 [...........,....]
0000000064 84 DC 00 00 00 14 01 32 00 01 00 00 84 F0 00 00 [.......2........]
0000000080 00 08 07 AD 00 02 00 00 84 F8 00 00 00 19 00 0F [................]
0000000096 00 02 00 00 85 11 00 00 00 00 01 2F 00 02 00 00 [.........../....]
0000000112 85 11 00 00 0D D3 01 2C 00 02 00 00 92 E4 00 00 [.......,........]
0000000128 00 14 01 32 00 02 00 00 92 F8 00 00 00 08 07 AD [...2............]
0000000144 00 03 00 00 93 00 00 00 00 19 00 0F 00 03 00 00 [................]
0000000160 93 19 00 00 00 00 01 2F 00 03 00 00 93 19 00 00 [......./........]
0000000176 59 7B 01 2C 00 03 00 00 EC 94 00 00 00 14 01 32 [Y{.,...........2]
0000000192 00 03 00 00 EC A8 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 04 00 00 [................]
0000000208 00 02 00 00 00 00 4E 43 53 41 20 48 44 46 20 56 [......NCSA HDF V]
0000000224 65 72 73 69 6F 6E 20 34 2E 32 20 52 65 6C 65 61 [ersion 4.2 Relea]
0000000240 73 65 20 30 2C 20 44 65 63 65 6D 62 65 72 20 32 [se 0, December 2]
0000000256 2C 20 32 30 30 33 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [, 2003..........]
0000000272 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [................]
0000000288 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 [............JFIF]
0000000304 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 FF DB 00 43 00 10 [.............C..]
0000000320 0B 0C 0E 0C 0A 10 0E 0D 0E 12 11 10 13 18 28 1A [..............(.]
0000000336 18 16 16 18 31 23 25 1D 28 3A 33 3D 3C 39 33 38 [....1#%.(:3=<938]
0000000352 37 40 48 5C 4E 40 44 57 45 37 38 50 6D 51 57 5F [7@H\N@DWE78PmQW_]
0000000368 62 67 68 67 3E 4D 71 79 70 64 78 5C 65 67 63 FF [bghg>Mqypdx\egc.]
0000000384 DB 00 43 01 11 12 12 18 15 18 2F 1A 1A 2F 63 42 [..C......./../cB]
0000000400 38 42 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 [8Bcccccccccccccc]
0000000416 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 [cccccccccccccccc]
0000000432 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 [cccccccccccccccc]
0000000448 63 63 63 63 FF C0 00 11 08 01 A0 01 C0 03 01 22 [cccc..........."]
0000000464 00 02 11 01 03 11 01 FF C4 00 1F 00 00 01 05 01 [................]
0000000480 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 03 [................]
0000000496 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B FF C4 00 B5 10 00 02 01 [................]
```

How can I convert it to jpeg to view its content (that is supposed to be an image)?
Is this conversion necessary or would You reccomend a software that can open it as I like?
I hope someone could help me, thanks in advance.

**ANSWER**

(As I can't answer my own question right now, I'm doing it here...)

At the end I came up with a solution thanks to the input information of unwind.
I downloaded HEX editor (http://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-hex-editor) to edit my binary file. Then I searched for the string where the 0xff 0xd8 was (in may case in line 0000000288). This is supposed to be the beginning of a JPEG file. Then I deleted everything that came before of that (also the six pair of zeros within the same line). Then I saved m edits and tried again to open it with an image processing program (in my case, I'm usin ENVI), and....IT WORKS! Now the binary file is red as an image file!
The problem now is that I have plenty of those files (302), and I need to edit all of them. Moreover, they each contain more than one jpeg, so I need to modify each one ore times. Guess I need to improve my programming knowledge...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, according to [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files) JPEG files begin with the byte pair `0xff 0xd8`, so you could search forwards for that sequence, and throw away the data before it.

In your file, it happens on the line starting `0000000288`.

Comment: Thanks, but how could I modify it? Your suggestion would be to delete everythig that comes before the line 0000000288 and trying opening it with a proper program, right?

Comment: Hey, it worked!... I really don't believe the workaround I had to do. Thank You so much, in the answer I am about to explain exactly what I've done, so everyone could do the same if needed.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub user [GrayedFox](https://gist.github.com/GrayedFox) has written a quick [gist](https://gist.github.com/GrayedFox/8cabb5bc81312cbff0a0a9244683d06c) in Python3 that looks for JPEG start/end markers in a file and extracts what it finds.

```
$ python3 ./extract-jpg myfile.bin
Size: 765481 bytes

$ file myfile.bin-exracted-img.jpg
myfile.bin-exracted-img.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 0.00, aspect ratio, density 0x0, segment length 16
```